# How to recover sdb1?

Tags: filesystem, data-recovery

How to recover `sdb1`?
I had wiped the filesystem from the pendrive using this command:

```
sudo wipefs -af /dev/sdb1
```

This was a mistake. And now, I want to recover `/dev/sdb1`!

Like

[[image: here is the pic]

It should be `sdb/sdb1`, but `sdb1` is not there.
What can I do? (Can I do anything at all?)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there anyway to undo wipefs?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/557173/is-there-anyway-to-undo-wipefs)

Answer (score 0):

Yes I wipefs doesn't remove the actual data by default..

Duplicate of this question :-

[Is there anyway to undo wipefs?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/557173/is-there-anyway-to-undo-wipefs)